# Help with "FIELD_CUSTOM_VALIDATION_EXCEPTION" Batch class failed to update records

Tags: batch, exception, schedulebatch

I have a similar batch class and the problem is not with the logic.
public class SimpleBatch implements Database.Batchable{

```
public Database.QueryLocator start(Database.BatchableContext BC){
    return Database.getQueryLocator('SELECT Id,Name,Start_Date__c,End_Date__c,Active__c FROM 
                    Object__c WHERE Start_Date__c!=NULL AND End_Date__c!=NULL');
}

public void execute(Database.BatchableContext BC,List<Package__c> scope){
    Date todayDate = Date.today();
    List<Object__c> objsToUpdate = new List<Object__c>();
    for(Object__c obj:scope){
        if((obj.Start_Date__c <= todayDate) && (obj.End_Date__c >=todayDate)){
            if(pkgObj.Active__c != 'Yes'){
                pkgObj.Active__c = 'Yes';
                objsToUpdate.add(obj);
            }
        }else if((obj.Start_Date__c > todayDate) || (obj.End_Date__c < todayDate)){
            if(obj.Active__c != 'No'){
                obj.Active__c = 'No';
                objsToUpdate.add(obj);
            }
        }
    }
    update objsToUpdate;
}

public void finish(Database.BatchableContext BC){
    //code to send email that batch finished successfully.
}
```

}

|System.DmlException: Update failed. First exception on row 5 with id 0065000000FLPqjAAH; first error: FIELD_CUSTOM_VALIDATION_EXCEPTION, Fraud__c is required for this services.

Googled this error and I understand that it came from some existing validation rule's field that my batch class has nothing to do with. Also, Someone mentioned that we should look into  the record that throws this error. But my issue is, I have 1000 plus records existed in Testing org, Cannot go back and edit all the records to populate the field which is required.
Please help to fix this in anyway and How to roll back only the records that was failed instead of all. TIA.

Answer (score 0):

It's possible to allow partial completion of a DML operation by using the Database Class methods rather than straight DML operations like you're currently using.

In this case, you'd be able to use:

```
Database.SaveResult[] results = Database.update(objsToUpdate,false)
```

In saying this, I would say that if you're going to allow partial success of your Batch Class then you will need to take that into account. Appreciate that it sounds like you're not wanting to do a data cleansing operation of a non-production environment, but if you implement this then you may have inconsistencies with the expected results of your batch class in Production.

Details of the Database Class and it's methods are available [here](https://developer.salesforce.com/docs/atlas.en-us.apexref.meta/apexref/apex_methods_system_database.htm)
and the specific one you're looking for is the [update(recordsToUpdate, allOrNone)](https://developer.salesforce.com/docs/atlas.en-us.apexref.meta/apexref/apex_methods_system_database.htm#apex_System_Database_update_2) method

Comment: Thanks for the prompt response. I saw this method too to allow partial completion. But the thing is  we would not want to have inconsistencies as you mentioned. In addition to this, How can I fix the error for all the records? Because we don't even use the field that causes the exception, but is in the same object that I am updating. Any help would be much appreciated. TIA.

Comment: The only way to fix this error is to have all of those records conform to the rules that have been defined. If the field is no longer used then the validation rule should be re-examined to see if it is required still. If it's still required but just not used as part of your process that you're updating, then you're going to have to do a data cleansing process and go and update those records.

Comment: That field is still being used, but not part of my process. But yeah, I see your point. Thanks  you!!